# Java - Skip values in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to skip values using a for loop. Something like

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255 - but skip 128 to 159; i++) {

    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this at the beginning of your loop:

```
for(int i = 32; i < 256; i++) {
    if(i == 128) i = 160;
    //...
}
```

This is MUCH better than simply continuing. You don't want to iterate over 128 to 159; you'd be wasting time.

Comment: No, you _start_ with the if statement. At the very beginning of the loop, `if(i == 128) i = 160;`. That way, once it reaches 128, it's changed to 160 _before_ anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the elements that you do not want, like this:

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255; i++) {
    if (i >= 128 && i <= 159) continue;
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

or split the loop in two, like this:

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 127; i++) {
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
for(int i = 160; i <= 256; i++) {
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just for completeness, this is also possible

```
for (int i = 32; i <= 255; i = (i == 127 ? 160 : i + 1)) {
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255 - but skip 128 to 159; i++) {
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
    if(i == 127) {
        i = 160;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or add the test to the loop like a functional language:

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255; i++) if (i < 128 || i > 159) {
    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 32; i <= 255; i++) {
        if (i < 128 || i > 159) {
            char ascii = (char) i;
            System.out.println(ascii);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if statement inside your loop.-

```
for(int i = 32; i <= 255; i++) {
    if (i < 128 || i > 159) {
        char ascii = (char) i;
        System.out.println(ascii);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make two loops :

```
    int MIN = 128;
    int MAX = 159;

    for(int i = 32; i < MIN ; i++) {

    char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii);
}

    for(int i = MAX + 1; i < 255; i++){
     char ascii = (char) i;
    System.out.println(ascii); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for (int i=32; counter<=255; i++){
    if (counter>=128 && counter<=159) {
    continue;
    }
char ascii = (char) i;
System.out.println(ascii);
}
```